# What is best practice for asynchronous javascript error handling?

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns, express

I am interested what is considered best practice for handling errors from an asynchronous JavaScript function. I have given two examples below one which handles the error in an `if statement` and one which handles the success in the `if statement`. Previously I have always handled the error in the `if statement` but wondered whether this was the best approach. Please let me know which you consider to be the best approach and why?

```
function(err, res){
    if(err){
       // handle error
       return;
    }
    // code to handle response
}
```

or

```
function(err, res){
    if(!err){
       // code to handle response
       return;
    }
    // handle error
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: both looks equally correct, probably SO is not the right place to ask it

Comment: They are both equally performant, however from a logic and flow standpoint returning on error first will make the most sense at first glance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well depending on the flow of the data and that portion(I.e. API and or route) of the app, you have the option to pass the error to the next middleware. You can return both the data from the other middleware and return the errors that may have bubbled up during the request. It depends on if you need the program to stop executing or if its a minor error which just needs to be logged and move on. As stated in the comments both are equally accepted.

Answer (score -1):

Best practice is to use to `babel` and ES7 `async / await` with ES6 `Promises`, instead of callbacks.

Otherwise 1st option is more common IMO.